# Задача по нейросетям используя Матлаб

Tags: matlab

Здравствуйте не поможете с решением задачи в Матлабе буду Вам премного благодарен.

http://rghost.ru/55126122

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообще-то это учебное задание и вы должны его делать сами, вот если бы у вас что-то конкретное не получилось - тогда да, можно было бы задать. Могу подсказать один финт - ваш препод раздолбай и взял примеры из книги  "В.Дьяконов, В.Круглов. MATLAB 6.5 SP1/7 SP2+Simulink 5/6. Инструменты искусственного интеллекта и биоинформатики" в качестве задания (по крайней мере про президентов там точно было, про алфавит скорее всего тоже - алфавит вообще постоянно используется для демонстрации нейронных сетей, препод бы хоть на кириллицу перевел), причем раздел про нейронные сети в эту книгу перекочевал без серьезны изменений из В.Дьяконов, В.Круглов. Математические пакеты расширения MATLAB. Специальный справочник. Питер. 2001. (попереставляли абзацы насколько помню), а та книга в свою очередь во многом перевод мануалов на русский, мануалы у матлаба очень подробные. Кстати, в заданиях еще и устаревшая версия пакета нейронных сетей - в 2010b вышла новая версия пакета и newff считается устаревшим.

Если не секрет, в каком инсте преподы настолько раздолаи?

Comment: А есть ли исходники по этим задачам из тех книг? Можете если не затруднит залить? Это просто ознакомительное задание нужно так сказать набить руку. Есть вот такое решение похожее для 2-ой задачи но не совсем подходящее его нужно подправить что бы оно соответствовало ответом для второй задачи. Если не затруднит подправьте пожалуйста буду Вам очень признателен. Давно хотел Вам написать но тут нет функции отправить личное сообщение. Вы же как погляжу знаток Матлаба.

Comment: Вот это подобное решение которое нужно подправить.

http://rghost.ru/55175087

Comment: Есть ли исходники не помню, по-моему, да, залить не могу - у меня бумажная книга и не с собой (вторую когда-то смотрел на работе тоже в бумаге). Насчет знатока матлаба вы ошибаетесь, я его когда-то достаточно много использовал, но довольно ограниченно и в последние года два-три довольно редко, к тому же учили меня на 6.5 -7.0, а сейчас уже 8 версия, в которой многое поменяли (классы стали делать по другому, ряд тулбоксов тоже поменялся). Поправить вряд ли смогу - нету сейчас нигде под рукой матлаба, а гадать по коду без дебага как-то несерьезно.

Comment: Уточните - у вас есть решение, но в нем какая-то проблема? Тогда уточните что именно не получается и тогда моя фраза про убеное задание возможно будет не к месту

Comment: А вот решение по 3 задаче правда исп другой программный продукт а нужно в Матлабе.

http://rghost.ru/55175334